# Is there a way to send feedback directly from my app?

Tags: java, android, forms, user-feedback

I am developing an android app and I would like users to be able to send me feedback directly from the app. So far I have solved the problem with intent by starting an external app to send an email.

But I would like the user to be able to fill out a form (a simple textView) and, by simply pressing a button, he could send me a message.

**Is there any way I can implement this?**

I hope I explained myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways you can get feedback from user :

You can add [Google In-App-Review](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) . It is an API developed by google that lets you prompt users to submit Play Store ratings and reviews without the inconvenience of leaving your app or game.

You can add a form and and develop some backend that takes that data and adds it to database after that you can query the database to view all the feedbacks.
You can find lots of tutorials on internet related to this [CRUD Operation in MySQL Using PHP, Volley Android – Insert Data](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/crud-operation-in-mysql-using-php-volley-android-insert-data/)

You can also add send emails directly check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36255852/3995126 (I wouldn't recommend this as it requires you to hardcode your email and password from which the email will be sent)